# Python replace() method doesn't keep changes

Tags: python, string, replace, find

I have a string that I need to reconstruct with new values.
The string looks like this:

```
log = "2019-06-25T11:09:59+00:00 15.24.137.43 printer: powered up"
```

I have a list that already contains the values:

```
list1 = ["2019-06-25T11:09:59+00:00",  "15.24.137.43", "printer", "powered up"]
```

I have another list that contains the values that I am going to replace in the original log:

```
list2 = ["date", "ip_address", "device", "event"]
```

I have tried the following in python:

```
list2_iteration = 0
for field in list1:
    if(log.find(field) != -1):
        #print(field)
        log.replace(field,list2[list2_iteration])
    list2_iteration += 1
print(log)
```

What I want to obtain is the reconstructed log such as:

```
'date ip_address device event'
```

It seems like the `replace()` method doesn't keep changes. When I print the log, on the last line, it prints the original log which is:

```
2019-06-25T11:09:59+00:00 15.24.137.43 printer: powered up
```

Do you have any idea on how can I keep the changes on the log, so I can have it fully reconstructed at the end?
I would appreciate it if anyone would help!
Thanks!

Comment: `.replace()` is not an inplace method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String in python are immutable and `replace` **return** new string - it doesn't update old value. Try this:

```
list2_iteration = 0
for field in list1:
    if(log.find(field) != -1):
        #print(field)
        log = log.replace(field,list2[list2_iteration])
    list2_iteration += 1
print(log)
```